# PHP Regex - To accept all UTF-8 characters, No trailing spaces, Excluding a symbol, with a range between 2-16 length

Tags: php, regex, string, utf-8

I am having trouble trying to figure out the correct PHP regex to match these conditions:

- Accepts all UTF-8 Characters
- Accepts Numbers
- Accepts a string that is between the range of 2-16 characters
- Excludes the "@" symbol
- Accepts all other symbols for example: "!#$%^&*))¶¡ª£"
- Allows a single space between characters, but not multiple
- Does not pass with trailing spaces for example:

`"Hello World!" //should be true`

`" Hello World! " //should be false`

`"Hello   World!" //should be false`

The following examples should fail:

`"a" //should fail because the length is less than 2`

`"whatsup@gmail.com" //should be false because of @ symbol`

The following examples should pass:

`"£ª¡™ƒ˚å 象形字 123" //should be true`

`What's up? 123" //should be true`

`"!#$%^&*(){}-_+" //should be true`

So far what I have is:

`/^((?!@).)*$/`

This PHP regular expression currently accepts characters, excludes the @ symbol, and includes numbers.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear if you want to match or validate. I.e. you want to match each line that matches these conditions, you want to validate that all lines pass the conditions, or is it supposed to be only 1 line of input and validate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex to satisfy all the conditions:

```
/^(?=.{2,16}$)[^@\s]+(?:\h[^@\s]+)*$/gum
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hX4pT0/5)

Comment: May I ask what "gum" does?

Comment: `g - global, u - unicode, m - multiline` My demo link has detailed info on all this.

Comment: I've tested it out on http://www.phpliveregex.com/ with gum and it doesn't seem to work with it, however it works without gum. Is this just that it does not work when it is using preg_match?

Comment: There is no `g` (global) option in PHP. [See this PHP Demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dSf) (Use only `um` with `preg_matchl`)